# Prepros failed to compile when using gem breakpoint

Tags: susy-compass, breakpoint-sass, prepros

Whenever I try to include the "breakpoint" gem in me prepros-project, I'm getting this error:

```
error sass/main.scss (Line 3 of sass/_grid.scss: File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint.
```

Load paths:
  C:/xampp/htdocs/egoplan/sass
  C:/Program Files (x86)/Prepros/gems/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.13/stylesheets
  C:/Program Files (x86)/Prepros/gems/gems/susy-1.0.9/sass
  Compass::SpriteImporter)

C:\xampp\htdocs\egoplan\sass\main.scss

I tried to install/uninstall several versions of compass, sass, susy and breakpoints. doesn't work. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to use Prepro's advanced Compass options in order to require the Breakpoint gem and use it. See their [using third party Compass plugins](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/docs/sass-compass.html#using-third-party-compass-plugins) instructions.

A word of warning; we recommend using [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) to manage Ruby gem versions and compile through the command line as any other option may not (and probably won't) correctly handle dependencies. Breakpoint 2.4.x requires Sass 3.3.0+ and Compass 1.0.0+ and without Bundler, it's possible that Breakpoint won't work even if it's installed properly as incompatible versions of Sass and Compass may be used. See [Breakpoint's Installation](https://github.com/Team-Sass/breakpoint/wiki/Installation) page.